# What is a TCP Relay and when is it used?

Tags: tcp, udp

*Tcprelay is a TCP connection forwarder with load balancing capabilities. If compiled with TLS support, it may be used as SSL encryption wrapper.*

What are some practical applications of TCP relay?

Comment: That quote need a bit more context to make the question clear.

Answer (score 2):

TCP (and/or SSL/TLS) relays can be used to act as a proxy between two different networks.  Consider the case where you have some servers on an internal LAN, and for whatever reason you do not want those servers exposed to the public Internet.  But you'd like clients, outside of that LAN, to be able to connect to an application on those internal machines.  You can set up a TCP relay on *e.g.* your network DMZ, such that the relay accepts the TCP connection from outside, and *relays* those TCP bytes to the internal network.  To the outside client, that TCP relay *is* the application server.

Once you have this sort of setup, folks often say "wouldn't it be nice if my TCP relay wasn't hardcoded to talk to only *one* internal server; if it could balance the load across a *pool* of internal servers, that would provide more redundancy and processing capacity, right?".  This is when a TCP relay starts to look like a load balancer -- and, in many cases, load balancers *are* TCP relays.

TCP relays also allow for inspection of incoming (or outgoing) traffic, looking for malicious incoming bytes, or illegal (by *e.g.* corporate policy) outgoing bytes (such as leaking/sending Social Security Numbers, credit card numbers, or any other sensitive data; these fall under the DLP (Data Loss Prevention) sort of relays/proxies), and for manipulating/changing the data, or breaking the TCP connection, as necessary.

These are just a few of the use cases that TCP relays can help to address; some research will turn up much more information on this topic, I'm sure.

Hope this helps!